# show that a differential equation is exact

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the following equation is exact and find the general solution:

$$x't + x + t^2 = 0$$

I'm meant to write $f(t,x)$ as $S(t,x)$ and find out if the functions are continuous to find whether it is exact, but have no idea how to do this, please could someone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is $f$?  $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$x't + x = \frac{d}{dx} (t x)$$

for a quick solution.  To show the equation is exact, write the equation as $t \, dx + (x + t^2) dt = 0$.  Now show that there is some function $F$ such that $\partial F/\partial x = t$ and $\partial F/\partial t = x + t^2$.  Solving the former equation

$$F(x,t) = x t + g(t)$$

Now find $g$.  From the second equation, $g(t) = (1/3) t^3$, neglecting a constant.  So

$$F(x,t) = x t + \frac{1}{3} t^3$$

Solutions to the DE are given by $F(x,t) = C$, a constant.  You may check this solution with one obtained using the method I suggested at the top.

Comment: but how do i show it is exact?

Comment: See my edit above.